# Batch file ErrorLevel woes

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to upgrade some systems. I need to parse a date from an xml file and save it for use later in the file. The format of the date is yyyy\MM\dd.

What I have so far is:

```
@echo off    
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion    
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (ConnectionManagement.xml) do (    
    set str=%%G     
    set mydate=%%G    
    echo got-    
    echo %%G    
    echo %mydate%    
    PAUSE

    ECHO %mydate%|findstr /R /C:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9] > nul    
    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto valueok    
)

echo DONE    
PAUSE

goto end    

:valueok    
echo VALUEOK

:end    
PAUSE
```

Unfortunately this incorrectly recognised the xml header as a valid date; but I think this is to do with ErrorLevel being reset (?). mydate isn't being set, and it recognises the empty variable mydate as a match (!!??). The output is:

```
got-    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
ECHO is off.    
Press any key to continue . . .
VALUEOK    
Press any key to continue . . .
```

...

Getting rather desperate for a solution. thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ErrorLevel is not being reset. What is actually happening is that `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` does not behave the way you expect. Basically, the test is not "Does errorlevel equal 0?", its "Is errorlevel greater than or equal to zero?". Given this, it should be clear that `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` will always be true (at least, if you only expect positive errors...)

Therefore, you need to use `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto valueok` instead.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thanks. Now what about mydate not being set correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Joey Hence my comment `at least, if you only expect positive errors` ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry; overlooked that one :)

Comment: @kreid: You set the variable and use its value in the same block. Variables in such a block are expanded (and replaced by their value) when it is read, not when it is run. Therefore `%mydate%` will just be replaced by the value the variable had before the loop. Use delayed expansion and `!mydate!` instead (see `help set`).

Answer (score 0):

As RB wrote, `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` does not behave the way you expect.

The `if errorlevel` is a special IF-case.
To use a normal IF-construct you could use

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
FOR-LOOP .. DO (
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 goto valueok
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. 

Do you know my "mydate" is not being set when i do:
set mydate=%%G
??